# How to safely manage connected user

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, cookies

I think that I figure dout how to do this:

When my user connect, after checking if he has the good username/password, a session key (a random long string) is created and put inside the DB. The same session_key is put inside the session.

If the user get out of my app without login off, when he comes back, if his session_key match one in the DB, the user is O.K and will connect as the user that have that session_key. If not, the session is closed, the user is rerouted to login. If there's no problem, a new session_key is created (to replace the old one).

I think it would be O.K., except for 2 things:

-How can I make the session_key disappear from DB after a certain time? I guess I should execute some code on the server, but how can I execute code on the server if nobody is using my app for a certain moment?

-If it's just the session_key, is it alright to use the cookie insted?

-Is it O.K. to just check if there's a session_key in the DB that correspond to the session_key in the session, or should I use something else to be sure? I will generate a random long string and crypt it the same way I do with password, so i think it will be secured enough and that it wouldn't be likely that the session_key be identical.

-insteed of using the username to get data from the DB, would it be O.K. to use the session_key (getStuffBySessionKey())?

Comment: Do not associate the content of the cookie to anything else other than authenticating. Use the contents on the server after authenticating to do anything.

Comment: If you are unsure how to correctly use cookies with a login system - use sessions. They're are safer to use (you can even fill it with userdata, since it will get saved on the server).

Comment: If you just store the key together with username and password you can do one check that both are valid or reroute to login

Comment: you absolutely should use session for admin privilege. perhaps it's easier to store an entire user object there and read it as needed. just use cookie for session ID.

Comment: So, my logic is good, accept that I should just put the username and the session_key inside the sessions (i feel like it would be dangerous the put the password in it even if it his crypted)?

Comment: PHP sets its own cookie, PHPSESSID or smth (it's configurable) to match user to a session. while there's a whole set of vulnerabilities based on session fixation etc, it's ok for basic cases. just store the user data in session or read it whenever needed.

Comment: So I should check the session_key when the user quit and comeback, but while he is on the app, I just use the information in the session? I don't need to recheck everything every time a request to the DB is made or when the route changes?

Comment: I just edited my question. I think I found a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What if my user access the cookie and change the username?

There's no need to store the username in the cookie. The cookie should *only* have the session key info. You'll get the username from that via db query when the user attempts to login. If the user changes the session key value in their cookie, then it will no longer match an active session in the database, and they will have to log back in. It's essentially the same as clearing the cookie.

> In addition to the username and the session_key, I will put the user privileges in the cookie. I will need it to know if the user is admin, creator or visitor.

These should be stored in the database as well, not in a cookie.

> Is there an other way to check if the user didn't try to change anything WHILE he still is on the app?

Nope, you should be checking for a valid, active session on every request from the user. If there's no session cookie, or if the cookie doesn't match a valid session, redirect them to the login page.

As others have pointed out, you'd be wise to use PHP's built-in sessions for all this.

Comment: When you say "every request from the user", you mean everytime a call to the database is done and everytime the route changes?

Comment: I mean on every page load (that should be protected by this login system) you need to check that the request has a valid session specified in the proper cookie. If not, send them to the login page!

Comment: The page only load once since it's AngularJS. It means that insted of on every page load, I need to check on every route change? Wouldn't that be to much request since it will need to check the user privileges in DB every time, or those it doesn't matter that much?

Comment: Sorry, you're getting outside of my area of expertise (I don't know much about AngularJS) - you might want to add that tag to your question.